# Linux - How to change version of PHP Cli?

Tags: linux, php, opensuse

I try to uninstall PHP CLI because I am running it with version 7.3.7 while I run the normal PHP with 7.2.5

I tried `apt-get purge php` but this only removed the normal PHP not the CLI php.

How can I uninstall the PHP CLI or change the version?

**Output of uname -a:**

```
Linux linuxphp7 4.12.14-lp150.12.67-default #1 SMP Tue Jul 9 08:18:26 UTC 2019 (b610084) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: opensuse does not use `apt`. Try `yum` or `zypper`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, apt works though, e.g. apt-get install xy

Comment: On debian based distributions (which use apt) the package is usually named `php-cli`. On a Frankenlinux with mixed pacakge systems ... who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which binary in use and then search for the rpm

```
which php
rpm -qa|grep php
```

Then check the version (`php -v`). After that delete that version if that is the one you want to get rid off.

Comment: Output of `which php` is : `/usr/local/bin/php`. Output of `rpm -qa  | grep php` is empty. Output of php -v is PHP 7.3.7

Comment: ok. this is good. so maybe you have installed it manually, outside of a package manager? is there a symlink in /usr/bin/php pointing to /usr/local/bin/php?

Comment: I deleted `/usr/local/bin/php` now `php -v` shows nothing. Then I installed php again with `zypper in php7 php7-mysql` and now it shows php 7.2.5. Thx!